# Jquery datepicker how to get current day in function beforeShowDay?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    beforeShowDay:  function(date) {
       var currentDay = date.getDate(); //how to get current Day
       return [true, "css"];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To set current date as default date:

```
$("#calendar").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```